# Is there an option to configure num stream thread for specific topic(s) instead of all?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

In our application we have multiple topics where some topics will be created with 16 partition and some topics will be created with 1 partition. Is there any `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings` property/option available to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: [num.stream.threads creating idle threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431844/num-stream-threads-creating-idle-threads)

If there is one `KafkaStreams` instance it is not possible because Kafka Streams does only have a global config. Hence, you would need to have multiple applications, i.e., multiple `KafkaStreams` instances that process different input topic to configure each with a different number of threads. Following the answer from above, it seems that spring-cloud-streams can create multiple `KafkaStreams` clients to support what you want.

However, I am not sure why you would want/need this (but I am also not exaclty sure how spring-cloud-stream translates your program)? In the end, parallelization is done based on *tasks* and thus for single input topic partitions only one of your thread will get the corresponding task assigned. Thus, there is no overhead you need to worry about.

For more details check out: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#parallelism-model

Answer (score -1):

There are several partition properties available. For example,

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.func-out-0.producer.partitionKeyExpression=payload.id
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.func-out-0.producer.partition
```

You can get more information on both producer and consumer configuration properties [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding-properties)