# num.stream.threads creating idle threads

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a spring boot kafka stream application with 2 topics consider topics A and B.Topic A has 16 partition and Topic B has 1 partition.Consider the application is deployed in 1 instance having `num.stream.threads`=16.
I ran kafka-consumer-groups.bat command to check how the threads are assigned to the partition in group,got  the following output.Topic A and B assigned with 16 threads where 14 threads in topic B is idle.

```
kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server 0.0.0.0:9092 --group <topic-AGroupName>  -describe
TOPIC     PARTITION      CLIENT-ID
topic-A    0          topic-AGroupStreamThread-429-consumer
topic-A    10         topic-AGroupStreamThread-422-consumer
topic-A    6          topic-AGroupStreamThread-425-consumer
topic-A    14         topic-AGroupStreamThread-431-consumer
topic-A    7          topic-AGroupStreamThread-420-consumer
topic-A    8          topic-AGroupStreamThread-428-consumer
topic-A    11         topic-AGroupStreamThread-430-consumer
topic-A    4          topic-AGroupStreamThread-417-consumer
topic-A    2          topic-AGroupStreamThread-427-consumer
topic-A    1          topic-AGroupStreamThread-418-consumer
topic-A    15         topic-AGroupStreamThread-421-consumer
topic-A    3          topic-AGroupStreamThread-424-consumer
topic-A    9          topic-AGroupStreamThread-419-consumer
topic-A    12         topic-AGroupStreamThread-426-consumer
topic-A    13         topic-AGroupStreamThread-432-consumer
topic-A    5          topic-AGroupStreamThread-423-consumer

kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server 0.0.0.0:9092 --group <topic-BGroupName>  -describe
TOPIC                               PARTITION                    CLIENT-ID
topic-BGroup-result-repartition     0            topic-BGroupStreamThread-683-consumer
topic-B                             0            topic-BGroupStreamThread-678-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-685-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-675-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-673-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-680-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-688-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-674-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-679-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-677-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-687-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-686-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-676-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-684-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-682-consumer
-                                   -            topic-BGroupStreamThread-681-consumer
```

How to avoid the idle threads in topic-B or is there any options available to set num.stream.threads per topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the concurrency property on the actual input binding. For e.g. `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<input-binding-name>.consumer.concurrency`. This gets mapped to `num.stream.threads` behind the scenes per input binding. See if that works and please let us know if you see any issues.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I tried enabling the above said configuration with 2 cases.

1.num.stream.threads: 16
   spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.topic-A-input.concurrency: 16
   spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.topic-B-input.concurrency: 1
There is no change in result.

2.num.stream.threads: 1
   spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.topic-A-input.concurrency: 16
   spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.topic-B-input.concurrency: 1
One thread is assigned to all the 16 partition in topic A and 1 thread assigned to 1 partition as expected.
Still not solved.

Comment: Sorry, you need `consumer` in the property definition. Please see my edits above.

Comment: Still no change in its behaviour.Thanks

Comment: Please create a small app and share it somewhere (GitHub maybe) where we can reproduce your issues.

Comment: Here is the sample https://github.com/sherin-javadev/cloud-stream-sample/tree/master/TestIdlethreadApp

Comment: i didn't realize before that you were using an older version of Spring Cloud Stream. Could you upgrade to the latest GA? 3.0.x which depends on boot 2.2.x. This particular concurrency feature didn't get added into the binder until 2.1.

Comment: Thanks.I have upgraded spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams to 3.0.2.RELEASE and boot to 2.2.4.RELEASE.Now with concurrency no idle threads created.There is another issue.Ideally the application should create the consumer groups with the name mentioned in spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<input>.group.While checking with "kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list" command its created with these names.For topicA  "ServerMainApplication-topicAListener-applicationId" and for topicB "demo-application".Also is there any patch applicable without upgrading boot version?

Comment: At the moment, there is no plan to patch the 2.0.x version with this feature. I suggest upgrading to the latest or the 2.1.x version of the binder that added this feature. With consumer group, I am not sure whats going on. Maybe start a new discussion focussing on that?

Comment: Solved the issue by upgrading  cloud stream version to 2.2.0.RELEASE and boot  version to 2.1.0.RELEASE and changes mentioned in 
 https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1508   .

Comment: @sobychacko I couldn't find corresponding configuration mapping for `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.<input-binding-name>.consumer.concurrency` However I did find it from `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<input-binding-name>.consumer.concurrency` as stated in this doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_special_note_on_concurrency 

I wonder if you made a typo in your answer, instead of `kafka.streams.bindings` it should simply be `bindings`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer.